build_runner stop to working after update
When I try to run dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-output I have the following uotput:
Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/src/bootstrap.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/bootstrap.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/bootstrap.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/src/executor.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/executor.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/executor.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/src/executor/isolated_executor.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/executor/isolated_executor.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/executor/isolated_executor.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/src/executor/multi_executor.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/executor/multi_executor.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/executor/multi_executor.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/src/executor/process_executor.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/executor/process_executor.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/executor/process_executor.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/src/executor/serialization.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/executor/serialization.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/executor/serialization.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/macros.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/api.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/api.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/src/executor/introspection_impls.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/executor/introspection_impls.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/executor/introspection_impls.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/src/executor/response_impls.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/executor/response_impls.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/executor/response_impls.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/src/executor/exception_impls.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/executor/exception_impls.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/executor/exception_impls.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macros-0.1.2-main.4/lib/src/executor/remote_instance.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../fvm/versions/stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/pkg/_macros/lib/src/executor/remote_instance.dart': No such file or directory
export 'package:_macros/src/executor/remote_instance.dart';
^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.7.0/lib/src/summary2/macro.dart:24:10: Error: Type 'macro.MacroInstanceIdentifier' not found.
  Future<macro.MacroInstanceIdentifier> instantiate({
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.7.0/lib/src/summary2/macro.dart:28:14: Error: Type 'macro.Arguments' not found.
    required macro.Arguments arguments,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.7.0/lib/src/summary2/macro.dart:35:14: Error: Type 'macro.ExecutorFactoryToken' not found.
  late final macro.ExecutorFactoryToken _executorFactoryToken;
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.7.0/lib/src/summary2/macro.dart:58:10: Error: Type 'macro.MacroInstanceIdentifier' not found.
  Future<macro.MacroInstanceIdentifier> instantiate({
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.7.0/lib/src/summary2/macro.dart:62:14: Error: Type 'macro.Arguments' not found.
    required macro.Arguments arguments,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.7.0/lib/src/summary2/macro.dart:116:14: Error: Type 'macro.ExecutorFactoryToken' not found.
  late final macro.ExecutorFactoryToken _executorFactoryToken;
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...

build_runner: ^2.4.12 and all generators injectable_generator, retrofit_generator, json_serializable and drift_dev at the last versions.
I tried to clean dart cache but without success.

Main issue here is absence of files which are part of Dart SDK (first lanes in error, bootstrap.dart and others). It may happen right after update because Dart SDK and binaries are not downloaded instantly. You can just run flutter doctor and dependencies will be downloaded. You will see something like this in you terminal before actual doctor output:
~ flutter doctor
Downloading Darwin arm64 Dart SDK from Flutter engine b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 97  201M   97  197M    0     0  11.3M      0  0:00:17  0:00:17 --:--:-- 12.2M

After that, those files will be available.

I think is not the problem, flutter doctor output is clean:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.1, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale en-IT)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.2.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
[✓] Network resources
• No issues found!

I use FVM to handle flutter versions, for some reason the stable version was broken. I removed and checked out the stable version and now works.
